# Android Firebase Cloud Messaging from device to device

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send firebase device to device push notifications, so I have the code as following.

```
private void sendNotification(final String token) {

    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
                JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
                JSONObject dataJson=new JSONObject();
                dataJson.put("body","Hello, I am body");
                dataJson.put("title","I am title");
                json.put("notification",dataJson);
                json.put("to",token);
                RequestBody body=RequestBody.create(JSON,json.toString());
                Request request=new Request.Builder()
                        .header("Authorization","key="+LEGACY_SERVER_KEY)
                        .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();
                String finalResponse=response.body().string();

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, finalResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

The problem here is the notification is not being sent to other device. But when I uncomment the Toast (last line of try block) the notification will send successfully and immediately it says app stopped working. Someone please help.

When I uncomment the Toast(last line of try block) notification will sent but it says unfortunately app stopped. The logcat is:

```
01-23 07:17:11.907 4694-4731/bhavana.apps.saveme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: bhavana.apps.saveme, PID: 4694
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:390)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:114)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:277)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:267)
        at bhavana.apps.saveme.MainActivity$6.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:199)
        at bhavana.apps.saveme.MainActivity$6.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:176)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only show Toasts in the UI thread.
Remove this line or move it to `onPostExecute`:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Toast.makeText()` needs to be executed in UI Thread. Try replace it with:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Or just use Log if you just need to debug:

```
android.util.Log.i("debug", "success msg: " + finalResponse);
```

You may check status of `doInBackground()` by overriding `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    android.util.Log.i("debug", "onPostExecute: " + result);
}
```

This assume `onPostExecute()` return `Boolean`, so:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ......

    // return true on success
    if (success) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Class needs to be defined this way:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

You should use [**`runOnUiThread`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is
>   the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current
>   thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
>   of the UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
 });
```